# c++ inheritance, vtable after casting

Tags: c++

given the next simple example,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public :
    void print() {
        cout<<"A print"<<endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
    void virtual print() {
        cout<<"B print"<<endl;
    }

};

int main() {
    A* aPointerB=new B();
    aPointerB->print();
    return 0;
}
```

the output is :
A Print

from my understanding :

```
new B()
```

creates an object on the heap with a virtual table that contains one method and that's B::print();
i have two ideas to why this is happening,

1. when casting the pointer to A is the virtual table entry for B::print() removed.
2. in runtime the program doesn't check the vtable entry for print() because we are of type A and print() is not virtual in A, therefor it runs A::print().

which one is it ?

### EDIT

it seems that my question wasn't clear, i know that A::print() is running because print() isn't virtual in A, my question is which of the 2 options is it for the reason print is running in A understanding the considering the way vtables and casting work.

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you didn't define print as virtual in A. That means that when calling on A objects, the lookup is not virtual.

Comment: that i understand, it was intentional, i am trying to understand how casting effects inheritance, what does it mean the lookup is not virtual ?

Comment: @james t: It doesn't. If you have a pointer to A, and the function was declared virtual, then a virtual lookup is used, else it isn't. It doesn't matter what inherited from A or defined what as virtual or anything like that. A virtual lookup decides the function to be called at run-time.

Comment: @james Your second hypothesis above is the correct one. The vtable entry isn't removed.

Comment: @james: It means that `aPointerB->print()` is resolved at compile-time, not run-time.  i.e. it always calls `A::print()`.

Comment: and if A was virtual then at compile time the compiler marks it as virtual lookup which happens at runtime ?

Answer (score 2):

`A`'s vtable doesn't contain any `print` function, since it's not virtual. For this reason if you call `print` on an object of type `A` the vtable isn't checked, and `A::print` (which is not virtual) gets called.

This means the code generated by the compiler just calls `A::print`, without even accessing the vtable.

Between your two ideas the second is the right one; the first one makes no sense: vtables are never modified at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` in `A` needs to be declared as `virtual`, not the one in `B` as you have it.